Antd table wrapped with Form.Item throws error "rowData.some is not a function"
I have this Form.Item and table component from ant design. At first, they render fine but when we try to change page, sort column or search in column, it throws this error rowData.some is not a function
this is how I'm wrapping it
<Form.Item
  name="clients"
  className="mt-4 mb-20"
  valuePropName="dataSource"
   >
     <Table
       size={tableSize}
       columns={columns}
       pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 10 }}
       scroll={{ y: "calc(100vh - 500px)", x: 800 }}
      />
</Form.Item>

This is not that common issue where dataSource is not an array, here, dataSource is an array but when we change something in table, that's when it throws the error. Have anyone encountered this error?

Can you please provide a code sandbox?
